# How to connect Github with Google Colab?

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

For my senior project, I need to use Google Colab because it's going to be about deep learning. As a Macbook Pro user, I can't use cuda because there is no Nvidia there. Since this is a group project, my team and I have to upload every step of our code to the Github repository. 2 members of our team have a Macbook Pro, so we can't use Visual Studio and have to use Google Colab. How do I connect Google Colab to Github so that we can fetch, commit and push our code?

I've looked at a few guides from YouTube, but it doesn't show how to edit a file cloned from Github in Colab.